# create variable 'workspace' not helping while using arcpy module in python (ArcGIS 10.5.1)

Tags: python, workspace, arcpy, arcmap

I am using python to project a dem file. The code I used is attached below:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Script arguments
Input_dem = "E:\\OneDrive\\Academic\\PhD\\Philemon\\phase_3_(model)\\dem_raw\\Mago_raw.tif"
Workspace = "E:\\OneDrive\\Academic\\PhD\\Philemon\\phase_3_(model)\\useful_data"
Output_Coordinate_System = "PROJCS['WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_46N',GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',93.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]" # provide a default value if unspecified

# Local variables:
reprojected = "%Workspace%\\reprojected"

# Process: Project Raster
arcpy.ProjectRaster_management(Input_dem, reprojected, Output_Coordinate_System, "NEAREST", "87.6969856825158 87.6969856825151", "", "", "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]")
```

The above code does the job of reprojecting the dem, but is not being stored in the assigned workspace. A little search with my novice search showed that the files are stored in the 'temp' folder under my username (windows).

using `arcpy.env.workspace` gets the job done, but I want to how to get the above code working. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `arcpy.env.workspace = "E:\\OneDrive\\Academic\\PhD\\Philemon\\phase_3_(model)\\useful_data"` 
instead of naked `workspace`variable

Comment: I had actually extracted the script from a model made from modelbuilder in Arcmap. The model seems to be working fine and giving me the desired results with the 'workspace' variable. However when I export the model as script, it stops working as desired. But your solution seems to help as I mentioned before. Wanted to know if there is any thing I am missing because for which I am not able to get the above code working.

Answer (score 0):

Is `%Workspace%` in

```py
reprojected = "%Workspace%\\reprojected"
```

a valid [Windows environment variable](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Environment_variable) on your system?

---

You don't necessary need to set `arcpy.env.workspace`. You should be able to do this:

```py
reprojected = Workspace + "\\reprojected"  # Python 2.7 / ArcMap
```